# Changing switch cases using add_action in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, action

A plugin has a public function as:

```
public function event_dashboard_handler() {
    $action = sanitize_title( $_REQUEST['action'] );
    $event_id = absint( $_REQUEST['event_id'] );
    try {
        switch ( $action ) {
            case 'duplicate' :
                $new_event_id = event_manager_duplicate_listing( $event_id );
            break;
            case 'delete' :
                wp_trash_post( $event_id );
        }
    do_action( 'event_manager_my_event_do_action', $action, $event_id );
    }
}
```

I want to change the *duplicate* switch case with ***my_own_function*** for which I am adding action as below but still it is picking up the old function and not picking up my function hence no results.

```
function change_duplicate($action, $event_id) {
    if ($action['duplicate'] ) {
        $new_event_id = my_own_function( $event_id );
        }
}
add_action( 'event_manager_my_event_do_action', 'change_duplicate', 10, 2);
```

Can anyone help where I am going wrong?

Comment: Here I am asking how to modify switch cases through add_action. The post you have referred as duplicate doesn't elaborate my request.

Comment: I have elaborated that after adding my action code, its not picking up my function.

Comment: I am still unable to sort out whats missing. That example is not helping me since its no where mentioned how to modify the switch cases using add_action. I am not much experienced in coding, I am new learner.

Comment: Already tried this, still its not picking up my function.

Comment: I have added print_r inside `my_own_function` but since its not picking up my function so I cant debug. Is their any way to debug the `add_action` itself?

Comment: The way `event_dashboard_handler` is built, you can't change the 'duplicate' behaviour. You can add a new behaviour but not replace the old one. Check if `event_manager_duplicate_listing` offers a way to change what you want.

Comment: unfortunately no way inside `event_manager_duplicate_listing` function. The only way is to modify this core function.

Comment: you have to debug before `if ($action['duplicate'] )`

Comment: Its still not picking up. I think its not recognizing my `add_action` code although it same as `do_action` ie. `event_manager_my_event_do_action`. Cant figure out whats getting wrong.